# How to sort an 2D array of Strings by a column which contains limited range of double values as Strings?

Tags: java, string, sorting, multidimensional-array, double

I have a String[][] array that looks like this.

All fields are stored as strings, doubles are concatenated into the array using "" +

```
01234567 Katie Brown         100.0 97.0  100.0   99.0  99.3    
20051005 Jack Chan           100.0 97.0  100.0   99.0  99.3    
02345678 John Smith          89.5  88.5  99.0    100.0 97.4
```

Assume that the double values range from 0.0 - 100.0

I wished to sort the array in descending order using the value of the last field (rightmost), so I used a custom comparator as such, which sorted the array in descending lexicographic value

```
// Sort the 2D array using the last column
Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<String[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String[] s1, String[] s2) {
        String t1 = s1[numberOfData - 1];
        String t2 = s2[numberOfData - 1];
        return t2.compareTo(t1); // Descending order
    }
});
```

This worked fine until I faced a situation where the last field was 100.0, like below

```
01234567 Katie Brown         100.0 97.0  100.0   99.0 100.0
```

It ends up coming dead last, since 100.0 is lexicographically lower than any other double value. (I think?)

Disregarding overhead and memory efficiency, is it possible to sort it by using the Double.parseDouble() value of the last field? How would I do so? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Do it properly: create a class for each object whose fields are currently stored as a String[], convert your String[] to a list of those instead, then sort them using Collections.sort() with a Comparator

Comment: One of options is `return Double.valueOf(t2).compareTo(Double.valueOf(t1));` but I agree with Bohemian, instead of array you should use proper class with fields which can hold your data like `Double someValue`. This will allow you to simply use `Comparator<YourClass>` and `compare(YourClass o1, YourClass o2){return o1.getSomeValue().compareTo(o2.getSomeValue());}`.

Comment: The problem is, I haven't learnt to use Lists nor Classes yet (in Java), and implementing classes will require me to rewrite a lot of other code from scratch. I understand it's bad programming technique, but I would really appreciate a one-off solution for now

Comment: In that case you should be fine with `return Double.valueOf(t2).compareTo(Double.valueOf(t1));`.

Comment: @Pshemo Thank you, that worked for me. I was trying Double.parseDouble() but that wasn't working for me (couldn't dereference type double error), could you explain why Double.valueOf() works instead?

Comment: Difference is in return types of Double.parseDouble and Double.valueOf methods. `int` is primitive type without methods, while `Double` is class with `compareTo` method.

Comment: and of course when you say `int` you mean `double`. @Pshemo

Comment: @DavidWallace of course :)